# SQL restore with cross referencing another database

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

When I restore a backup of `MyDatabase_PROD` to `MyDatabase_TEST` I have a cross Reference of another database in my TEST now that comes from prod.

For example a select in a view of

```
Select * from [My_DB_PROD].[dbo].[ID]
```

Insead of

```
Select * from [My_DB_TEST].[dbo].[ID]
```

So now I have to write a separate script for each stored proc, view etc to fix that.

Is there a way to restore and run a single script to change all of those references? I was looking into `db_name()` or `db_id` if exists do something with it but I think there is a better way.

Any ideas?

Comment: Is this view in a different database? If it's in the database `My_DB_PROD` then why are you reference the database it's in? The easier option would be to change to 2 part naming; then no matter what you call the database, the View will always refer to itself.

Comment: Otherwise, if they're in a separate database, the common method is to use synonyms, and script those out.

Comment: @Larnu it is a reference of a different database. You can add your answer if you wish.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would re-implement the Selects to other DBs as Local Synonyms.

That way you can have the same code in different regions.

Failing that - You could probably scan code for regular expressions with ?.?.? which would signal an external DB.

Or Another way is to Build up a list of prod DB Names (hopefully short)- then scan syscomments for these values& do a hard replace with the Dev values on the Dev DB

You can extract the text via a while loop vs syscomments- do a Replace() and Exec() the replaced SQL - Watch out for Giant sprocs that have multiple rows in syscomments

You'll probably need dbo or sa rights.

Edit to add SQL

```
DECLARE @SQL varchar(max)

WHILE EXISTS (select * from sys.syscomments where text like '%My_DB_PROD%')

BEGIN


select top 1 @SQL = Text from sys.syscomments where text like '%My_DB_PROD%'

SET @SQL = REPLACE(@SQL, 'My_DB_PROD','My_DB_TEST')

EXEC (@SQL)

END
```

NB - This doesn't handle giant procs - you can check if you have any of these with:

```
select object_name(id) , count(*) from syscomments 

group by object_name(id)

having count(*) > 1
```

If you do then its a bit trickier as you have to concat all the separate text values into a single sql statement (colid 1,2,3 etc)

Check if this is the case - it might not be!

SQL for BIG Procs Here:

```
DECLARE @SQL varchar(max)='', @colid int=1, @ID Int, @MaxColID int, @TempSQL varchar(MAX)

WHILE EXISTS (select * from sys.syscomments where text like '%My_DB_PROD%')

BEGIN

    select top 1 @ID= ID from sys.syscomments where text like '%My_DB_PROD%'

    SELECT @MaxColID = MAX(COLID) from sys.syscomments where ID = @ID

    WHILE @ColID <= @MaxColID

    BEGIN

        SELECT @TempSQL = Text FROM syscomments where ID = @ID and colid = @Colid

        Set @SQL += @TempSQL

        SET @ColID +=1

    END



    SET @SQL = REPLACE(@SQL, 'My_DB_PROD','My_DB_TEST')

    EXEC (@SQL)

    SET @SQL = ''

END
```

Comment: Can you add a short examples of these if possible?